# Method.invoke and exception

Tags: java, exception, methods, invoke

How can I use invoke in method `compare(T o1, T o2)`  if me

Comment: Comparators have to be optimized, using reflection in it is really a bad idea

Answer (score 2):

As Aubin pointed out: comparators are called very-very many times! Using a slow reflection in a comparator seems to be a suicide in a magnificent and glorious way. I can't imagine ever having to do that (just because the fact you <del>can't</del> shouldn't compare apples to oranges, and if you only have apples, you already know how to compare them)!

I don't see, why you want to  do this. If you'd post the code you have so far, this would be a lot more clear, and we could help you a lot better!

**However**, to answer your question on how to catch exceptions thrown by a method invoked through reflection:

Look at the API doc for [Method.invoke()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

It clearly states to throw an `InvocationTargetException` when the invoked method terminated by throwing an exception:

> [InvocationTargetException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html) - if the underlying method throws an exception.

so this is what you could do, using the `Throwable.getCause()` to get the original exception:

```
try {
    myMethod.invoke(myArgs...);
} catch(InvocationTargetException e) {
    Throwable myOriginalException = e.getCause();
}
```